# Date Formatting issue IOS

Tags: ios

Please help me.

I have date in string as **"2014-12-31 00:00:00"**

I am using following function to convert date from one format to another format.

```
NSDateFormatter * dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];


NSDate * dateNotFormatted = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"2014-12-31 00:00:00"];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMM yy"];
[dateFormatter setCalendar:gregorian];
NSString * dateFormatted = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:dateNotFormatted];
    dateFormatter = nil;
NSlog(@"Formatted Date %@", dateFormatted);
```

I am receiving output as **Formatted Date Dec 2015**.    I should get **Formatted Date Dec 2014** as output.
This code works fine for all other date.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.   I had written code as NSDateFormatter * dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];


NSDate * dateNotFormatted = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"2014-12-31 00:00:00"];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:[@"MMM yy" uppercaseString]];
[dateFormatter setCalendar:gregorian];
NSString * dateFormatted = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:dateNotFormatted];
    dateFormatter = nil;
NSlog(@"Formatted Date %@", dateFormatted);   It was creating problem.   I was sending wrong date format as [@"MMM yy" uppercaseString]

Answer (score 1):

I have check your code. for gregorian i have create variable like this

`NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];`

It's working. I get output:

`Formatted Date Dec 14`

Please check your system date also.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you've written for `gregorian`  but if you'd like to get exactly as **Formatted Date Dec 2014** as output, then you might want to set the calendar to `currentCalendar` like below:

```
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMM yyyy"]; //yyyy prints the year 2014
//  [dateFormatter setCalendar:gregorian];
    [dateFormatter setCalendar:[NSCalendar currentCalendar]];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you specifically want the Gregorian calendar, then use something like this:

```
NSCalendar *cal = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
[dateFormatter setCalendar:cal];
```

Otherwise `[NSCalendar currentCalendar]` is better.

With the explicitly Gregorian calendar as above, your code seems to work fine for me. I'm seeing "Dec 14" as the outputted date.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with the same code with minor change in SetCalender Line, and it is giving correct output like **Formatted Date Dec 14**,

```
NSDateFormatter * dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];

NSDate * dateNotFormatted = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"2014-12-31 00:00:00"];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMM yy"];
[dateFormatter setCalendar:[[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar]];
NSString * dateFormatted = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:dateNotFormatted];
dateFormatter = nil;
NSLog(@"Formatted Date %@", dateFormatted);
```